# Output a header label in data field in miller

Tags: text-processing, miller

Given *file.csv*:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
```

How can [`mlr`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) be made to output:

```
a,b,c
1,2,c
```

Using the label name of `$c` *without* knowing in advance that `$c` contains the letter "*c*"?

---

Note: correct answer must use `mlr` only.

Comment: do you want the last header column to be the last column value or all other records?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, In this simplest possible case either way would be fine.

Comment: I hadn't come across miller - `mlr` - before - looks great, will have to spend some time playing with it and reading the docs. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Questions: 1. Is this supposed to always refer to field 3 or the last field?  2. If there is more than 1 line of data following the headers, should all lines of the data be changed, or only the first line?

Comment: @LS, Sensible corner-case questions, but the disappointing answer is *"doesn't matter (to me)"* --  I asked the Q. because extracting **a** field name from a header, (not any particular field), seemed like a simple thing, (and should be given the scope of `mlr`), but I couldn't find a simple method.  The `a,b,c\n1,2,3\n` was my attempt to give a minimal data instance.

Comment: If you don’t care about how it handles the general case, then ``printf '%s\n' a,b,c 1,2,c`` will do what you want.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', This Q. ***is*** about the general case.

Comment: Well, that would be the standard presumption.   My point is that, even when presented with specific clarifying questions, you have refused to identify the general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Edited answer***

Hi,
you could use this script

```
mlr --csv put 'if (NR == 1) {
counter=1;
  for (key in $*) {
    if (counter == 3) {
    $[key]=key;
    }
    counter += 1;
  }
}' input.csv
```

And as output you will have:

```
a,b,c
1,2,c
```

`NR == 1` to have the first row, and `counter == 3` to get the third field.

Comment: Gives an error if the last line of the file ends with a line break, which is not an uncommon thing. (`Header/data length mismatch (3 != 1) at file "input.csv" line 3.`)  I think this is a miller feature, though, not a problem of this script.

Comment: You say "`NR == 1` to have the heading row", but that's not actually what it does.  When `NR` equals `1`, that's the first row of data, which is the line *after* the heading row.

Comment: @LS I have no error  if the last line of the file ends with a line break. I'm using mlr 5.7

Answer (score 2):

Simply with **`awk`**:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ (NR == 1)? c=$NF : $NF=c }1' file.csv
```

Sample output:

```
a,b,c
1,2,c
```

Comment: Thanks & sorry -- I'm at fault for not specifying that a `mlr`-only answer is required.  (I'm trying to learn `mlr`, but it can be puzzling.)  *Q.* revised to reflect language limitation.  +1 because it works tho'...

Comment: The awk script doesn't work without `1` at the end, but why?

Comment: I see why `1` is needed.  It's a pattern that's always true.  A pattern without an action prints the current line.  Clever, but not intuitive.  It'd be better to explicitly print, i.e., `awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ (NR == 1)? c=$NF : $NF=c; print }' file.csv`.

Comment: @LS The `1` trick is a common idiom in AWK; I agree it’s not intuitive, and you can avoid it in your own programs, but you’d end up having to learn it quickly if you read a lot of other people’s AWK programs ;-).

Answer (score 2):

**miller** *v5.6.0* allows the use of *`$[[fieldno]]`* to refer to the value of the name of field number *"fldno"*, so in your case field 3's name is `$[[3]]`.

```
    mlr --csv put '$c = $[[3]]' file.csv
```

Comment: That sounds ideal, but on my system with `mlr` *v5.3.0-1*, the above code fails with two errors:  `mlr DSL: syntax error at "["` and `mlr put: syntax error on DSL parse of '$3 = $[[3]]'`.

Comment: Apologies for that.  I only just started using miller and am using the latest stable level of miller from Homebrew,version 5.6.0, where that syntax is accepted and supported.  May I suggest you upgrade?  Homebrew makes that so very easy to do.

Comment: Homebrew may be easy, but SFAIK it's an *OSX* installer util rather than a *Linux* one.  I'm running *Ubuntu 18.04*, so the easiest available upgrade is `mlr` *v5.4*, (from [pkgs.org](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/miller/miller_5.4.0-1_amd64.deb)), but *v5.4* can't returns the same error.  Using `alien` on [miller-5.6.0-alt1_1.x86_64.rpm from pkgs.org](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/miller/miller_5.4.0-1_amd64.deb) does successfully install  however.

Comment: ...but *v5.6* outputs: `a,b,c,3` (linefeed) `1,2,3,c`, which is incorrect.

Comment: There's a typo in the solution.  At least for Miller 5.7.0.  The `$3` should be `$c`, then it produces the correct answer.

Comment: @LS the original answer didn’t work in Miller 5.6 either; but it’s not clear from the question that the answer is allowed to use the third column’s label...

Comment: @StephenKitt, you're right.  I glossed over that part of the question.  I have an update.  I also wonder whether the change is to always apply to the *_third_* field or the *_last_* field, and whether it's to apply to the *_first_* line of data or *_all_* lines.